# Trigger event on return in C++

Tags: c++

I want to execute some function right before the return of another function. The issue is that there are multiple returns and I don't want to copy-paste my call before each of them. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
void f()
{
    //do something
    if ( blabla )
        return;
    //do something else
    return;
    //bla bla
}
```

I want to call g() before the function returns.

Comment: Write a dispatcher: `void call_f() { f(); g(); }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
struct DoSomethingOnReturn {
  ~DoSomethingOnReturn() {
    std::cout << "just before return" << std::endl;
  }
};
...
void func() {
  DoSomethingOnReturn a;
  if(1 > 2) return;      
}
```

Comment: @loki2302 nice trick, but seems overkill to me... I'd just wrap any complexity within a simple function call and return it for syntax sugar

Comment: @Lea Hayes: Why? Simple and idiomatic solution.

Comment: @loki2302 there is going to be more overhead (depending upon how good the optimizer is) because of unwinding the stack and calling destructors. A simple function is called explicitly so it should theoretically be more efficient. And you can avoid defining structs/classes as a simple function can do the trick. Just my personal preference.

Comment: @Lea: premature optimization in the flesh... . Very likely with modern compilers this will make no difference (RAII is to important to not optimize it)

Comment: @Lea Hayes: Well, in theory compiler is permited to do whatever it wants while semantics is the same.

Answer (score 7):

There are some ways to do this.
One would be to use [boost::scope_exit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) or use a struct and do your work in the destructor.
I dislike the preprocessor syntax of boost and I am too lazy to write struct so I prefer using a boost::shared_ptr or on newer compilers a std::shared_ptr. Like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<void>(nullptr, [](void*){ /* do your stuff here*/ });
```

Comment: +1, nice! in fact, i think boost should have a version of scope_exit which leverages this on c++0x compilers!

Answer (score 4):

This is often a sign that instead of trying to artificially do something before every return, you should try to refactor your function into single-exit form. Then it's super easy to do your extra step because...there's only one return.

Comment: What happens if an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 4):

I think try-finally statements will do what you want.

```
void f()
{
    __try
    {
       //do something
       if ( blabla )
           return;
       //do something else
       return;
      //bla bla
    }
    __finally
   {
      g();
   }
}
```

> The try-finally statement is a Microsoft extension to the C and C++
>   languages that enables target applications to guarantee execution of
>   cleanup code when execution of a block of code is interrupted. Cleanup
>   consists of such tasks as deallocating memory, closing files, and
>   releasing file handles. The try-finally statement is especially useful
>   for routines that have several places where a check is made for an
>   error that could cause premature return from the routine.

Quoted from [msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xtt5hxz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: It's not C++, it's Microsoft-specific extensions.

Comment: Already mentioned that in my answer. its a Microsoft extension to C and C++. But I don't think using an extension makes it non-C++.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define RETURN_IT g(); \
        return;

void f()
{
    //do something
    if ( blabla )
        RETURN_IT;
    //do something else
    RETURN_IT;
    //bla bla
}
```

Simple, although I do kind of like loki's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of thing, you could simply use a boolean. That way you don't have too many if/else statements:

```
void f()
{
    //do something
    done = false;
    if ( blabla )
        done = true;
    //do something else

    if (!done) {
        // some code
        done = true;
    }

    if (!done) {
        // some other code
        done = true;
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void f()
{
    //do something
    if ( blabla )
        return;
    //do something else
    return;
    //bla bla
}

void f_callg()
{
    f();
    g();
}
```

If there is no access to where f() is called from

```
void f_copy_of_old()
{
    //do something
    if ( blabla )
        return;
    //do something else
    return;
    //bla bla
}

void f()
{
f_copy_of_old();
g();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int g() {
    // blah
    return 0;
}

void f() {
    // do something
    if (blabla)
        return g();
    // do something else
    return g();
}
```

Comment: @Luchian sorry I misread your question, I have updated my answer